# Can someone explain callbacks?

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be a lack of information on callbacks, or at least hard to find, so I was wondering if someone here could understand them. Right now, they seem like magical functions. I'd never heard of them before, and the Internet hasn't been entirely helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39123/can-someone-explain-callbacks?/) by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-07-18**:
Thanks, that's basically what I've discovered. I had just never heard of it before and they're incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A callback is a function that you do not call yourself, but define it yourself. Usually you pass the function pointer to another component that will call your function when it seems appropriate.

In the ROS setting a callback in most cases is a message handler. You define the message handler function and give it to subscribe. You never call it yourself, but whenever a message arrives ROS will call you message handler and pass it the new message, so you can deal with that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-18**:
Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-07-24**:
Note that ROS won't call your callback automatically.  You have to tell it to spin.

**Comment by [ningmang208](https://answers.ros.org/users/60660/ningmang208/) on 2020-10-08**:
I have a question: what's the convenience of a callback function, I think I still can write normal code to realise the functionality of callback. So, why do we have to use callback?